# Spring Boot Can't get the relation entity with findAll or findByColumnName method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm just trying to test the relation @ManyTonOne in Spring Boot (Spring Data JPA)n so I've created two simple Class Book and Author

Here is the Class Book and Author :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
//@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
private Author author;
```

Class Author:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "fullname")
private String fullame;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Book> books;
```

I just want when i try to call findAll() for books i get author also, when i make it by default i get this result without the author :

```
"_embedded": {
    "books": [
      {
        "title": "Book1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/books/1"
          },
          "book": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/books/1"
          }
        }
      },
```

Or when i write directly method findAll in controller :

```
@RestController
public class BookRestController {

@Autowired
BookRepository bookRepo;

@RequestMapping("/books1/")
public List<Book> createInvoice() {
    List<Book> list = bookRepo.findAll();
    System.out.println(list);
    return list;
}
```

i get this result :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Book1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Book2"
    },
```

I've tried also to search by title findByTitle(string), I don't get the author also

A different example that I found is about the second relation @OneToMany, not the other way

What I must add in my Entity or repository or controller to retrieve (with a good way) the author id?

Comment: hm, if you miss the author, what did you intend with the JsonIgnore

Comment: By using `@JsonIgnore` you are ignoring author in response.

Comment: I've add @JsonIgnore because when i remove it  igot 404 not found : 

{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-06T13:54:46.510+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/books/"
}

Comment: It's unrelated I think, path is not found, may be because you are using `/books1/` in controller not `/books/`

Comment: Your path is "books1"

Comment: same thing with books1 :

{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-06T13:59:47.644+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/books1/"
}

Comment: Can you add your full stack trace from your console of application ?

Comment: In the console, i've unlimited logs like this : 

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think without the JsonIgnore maybe you're just going right into recursion hell, since the book has an author and the author has minimum this book, and the book has the author...

Try a getter on the AuthorId, something like

```
 public Long getAuthorId() {
    return (author == null) ? null : author.getId());
}
```

EDIT:

wrote the maybe before your comment, now I'm quite sure :-)

Comment: When i add this, i got the same error unlimited times in the log and also i got the result with unlimited recursion :

 {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Book1",
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "fullame": "Faycal",
            "books": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Book2",
                    "author": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "fullame": "Faycal",
                        "books": [

Comment: the JsonIgnore on author back in place?

Comment: Thank u so much, i've add again @JsonIgnore and it works without any error

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@JsonIgnore` and use `@JsonIdentityInfo` on both classes to get author also for every book.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
public class Book {
  ...
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
public class Author {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I got this error : 

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.faycal.relation.entity.Book["author"]->com.faycal.relation.entity.Author$HibernateProxy$GdSp65g5["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from

Comment: Are you remove @JsonIgnore and use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) ` since you have lazy invocation

Comment: I've tried the previous solution, i'll do this also